# Magento Authorized and Capture issue

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net, credit-card

Is there a way to Capture less than what was originally authorized? We sell products that face a tariff on steel and aluminum products coming from China. We would like to authorize the product for the amount to include the tariff but once we fill the order from our vendors we will only then know if the tariff applies. When that does we would like capture the amount without the 10% tariff.